# dyn4j how to achieve a borderless world

Tags: java

I am trying to make an asteroids game where if you go out the top of the screen you appear at the bottom, and so on with left an right. how I achieved this was have an object where it has shapes shifted by the entire length of the board. This means we have 5 objects ,center, left, right, up, down and physics on any of them is applied as one object. is this possible with dyn4j?

I tried making multiple objects shifted, but I dont know how to link the phisics and positioning together.

Answer (score 0):

I went by extending the body class and having subBodies, updating the rotation velocity position etc.

Heres a link where I may expand more on it.

https://github.com/dyn4j/dyn4j/discussions/265